# number of functions with fixed point from finite set in itself

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, fixed-points

For a given set $A$, with $|A|=n, \, n\in\mathbb{N}$, I want to know the cardinality of $$M:= \{f:A\rightarrow A| f \mbox{ has at least one fixed point}\}.$$

Does anyone know if this is possible and if yes has a source or a answere for me?

Comment: @drhab, thank you, but this would be the special case if f is a permutation. I'm asking explicit for all functions.

Comment: @Maxiquester you might be able to use this in tandem with induction on the size of the image of $f$.

Comment: The same idea of applying inclusion-exclusion works here for general functions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the set of functions from $A$ to itself such that $i$ is a fixed point.

We try to count $\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right|$

Clearly $|X_i| = n^{n-1}$ as each of the $n-1$ elements in the domain apart from $i$ have $n$ options for where they map to.

Similarly, $|X_i\cap X_j|$ with $i\neq j$ is of size $n^{n-2}$ as each of the $n-2$ elements apart from $i$ and $j$ have $n$ options each for where they map to.

Expanding the above via [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), we arrive at a final count of:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1}\binom{n}{i}n^{n-i}$$

---

Alternatively, we can count the opposite event.

If *no* element were a fixed point, then each element has $n-1$ options.  Subtracting this from the total:

$$n^n - (n-1)^n$$

which you can find is equal to the above.

Comment: Right, this is clear.